# Jquery adding validate rules on select dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble making dynamically added inputs required. especially with the "select" input

I have already tried manually checking (wo Jquery validate) if inputs submitted were correct but i encountered the same kind of problem. The "required" class doesn't help either.

Here's the html :

```html
<form id='myform'>
  <div>
    <div id="addRow">+</div>
    <div id="deleteRow">-</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="tableex">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="selectbox[]" data-selected="" class='selectdyna required'>
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">env :</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type='submit' value='Validate'>
  </div>
</form>
```

here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {

    var str = "<tr>\n" +
      "                <td id=\"selecttd\">\n" +
      "                    <select name=\"selectbox[]\" class='selectdyna required' data-selected=\"\">\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\" >env :</option>\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"1\">option1</option>\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"2\">option2</option>\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"3\">option3</option>\n" +
      "                    </select>\n" +
      "                </td>\n" +
      "            </tr>";
    $("#tableex").append(str)
     $('#myform').validate();
        $('.selectdyna').rules('add',  { 'required': true });
  })
  $("#deleteRow").click(function() {
    if ($("#tableex tr").length > 1) {
      $("#tableex tr:last").remove();

    } else {
      alert("there must been one line minimum.")
    }
  })
})
```

here's a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3tj2c5u/

Comment: Jquery validations work on Input's name property. You are giving the same name in each input that's why it is showing single error and when you select one of them then the error is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you require the name of the dropdown that way.
You can do it as below demo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
   var count= $("#tableex tr").length+1;
    var str = "<tr>\n" +
      "                <td id=\"selecttd\">\n" +
      "                    <select name=\"selectbox"+count+"\" class='selectdyna required' data-selected=\"\">\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\" >env :</option>\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"1\">option1</option>\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"2\">option2</option>\n" +
      "                        <option value=\"3\">option3</option>\n" +
      "                    </select>\n" +
      "                </td>\n" +
      "            </tr>";
    $("#tableex").append(str)
     $('#myform').validate();
        $('.selectdyna').rules('add',  { 'required': true });
  })
  $("#deleteRow").click(function() {
    if ($("#tableex tr").length > 1) {
      $("#tableex tr:last").remove();

    } else {
      alert("there must been one line minimum.")
    }
  })
})
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9w6y0svh/1/)

Comment: The idea behind was to get the result in an array when I post my form. Also I thought this was the only way to do it. Guess I'll try your way since it seems to have fix a lot of my other problems ^^. I guess this is a good fix but I would also like to understand why my solution wouldn't work. Thx a lot for your help.